# Yahoo CalDAV: Bad request on getting calendars

Tags: icalendar, yahoo-api, caldav

I'm developing a calendar client for CalDAV servers. My application is OK working with Google CalDAV. I'm trying to get calendars from Yahoo calendar. What's wrong with the request causing Bad request error?

Getting options request:

```
OPTIONS https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com/dav/aliasgarikh/Calendar/testcalendar HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Host: caldav.calendar.yahoo.com
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Getting options response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Sun, 05-Jun-2016 20:11:56 GMT
WSHost: tardis018.cal.bf1.yahoo.com
DAV: 1, 3, access-control, extended-mkcol, calendar-access
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Allow: MKCOL, REPORT, MOVE, COPY, HEAD, POST, GET, DELETE, MKCALENDAR, ACL, PROPFIND, OPTIONS, PROPPATCH, PUT
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2016 20:11:55 GMT
Server: ATS
Age: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Via: http/1.1 calgate116.cal.ne1.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer)
```

Getting calendars request:

```
PROPFIND https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com/dav/aliasgarikh/Calendar/testcalendar HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Depth: 0
Host: caldav.calendar.yahoo.com
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 103

<options xmlns="DAV:">
  <calendar-collection-set xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" />
</options>
```

Getting calendars response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Sun, 05-Jun-2016 20:11:57 GMT
WSHost: tardis041.cal.bf1.yahoo.com
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3190
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2016 20:11:56 GMT
Server: ATS
Age: 2
Connection: keep-alive
Via: http/1.1 calgate116.cal.ne1.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer)

<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Yahoo! - Error report</title>
    <style>
        /* nn4 hide */ /*/*/
        body {
        font: small/ 1.2em arial, helvetica, clean, sans-serif;
        font: x-small;
        text-align: center;
        }

        table {
        font-size: inherit;
        font: x-small;
        }

        html>body {
        font: 83%/ 1.2em arial, helvetica, clean, sans-serif;
        }

        input {
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        }

        p,form {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }

        p {
        padding-bottom: 6px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #doc {
        width: 48.5em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        text-align: center;
        }

        #ygma {
        text-align: right;
        margin-bottom: 53px
        }

        #ygma img {
        float: left;
        }

        #ygma div {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        margin-left: 152px;
        }

        #bd {
        clear: both;
        text-align: left;
        width: 75%;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
        }

        h1 {
        font-size: 135%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 0 15px;
        }

        legend {
        display: none;
        }

        fieldset {
        border: 0 solid #fff;
        padding: .8em 0 .8em 4.5em;
        }

        form {
        position: relative;
        background: #eee;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-width: 1px 0;
        }

        #s1p {
        width: 15em;
        margin-right: .1em;
        }

        form span {
        position: absolute;
        left: 70%;
        top: .8em;
        }

        form a {
        font: 78%/ 1.2em arial;
        display: block;
        padding-left: .8em;
        white-space: nowrap;
        background: url(http://l.yimg.com/a/i/s/bullet.gif)
        no-repeat left center;
        }

        form .sep {
        display: none;
        }

        .more {
        text-align: center;
        }

        #ft {
        padding-top: 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid #999;
        }

        #ft p {
        text-align: center;
        font: 78% arial;
        }
        /* end nn4 hide */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="doc">
    <div id="ygma">
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">
            <img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/yahoo.gif" width="147"
                 height="31" border="0" alt="Yahoo!">
        </a>

        <div>
            <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>
            - <a href="http://help.yahoo.com">Help</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bd">
        <h1>HTTP Status 400 - Error:400</h1>

        <p>
            <b>type</b>
            Status report
        </p>

        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>Error:400</u>
        </p>

        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u>
        </p>

        <p>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PROPFIND` request is completely invalid. The payload of a `PROPFIND` request (given there is one) has to have a `DAV:propfind` root element. See [RFC 4791, section 8.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-8.4) for a valid request to retrieve the calendar-home-set.

The only reason why this works with Google is because their server seems to be rather tolerant and returns some kind of default response (similar to like it would respond when you don't send any message body).

Comment: can you please  answer this question for me. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66312856/caldav-yahoo-report-free-busy-query-resulting-in-500-server-error](caldav response 500 server error)